C# AccessViolationException keyboard hooking
My project is using C# .net 4.7.2
My program is forced to close once every 1-2 days.
Checking the Windows event log
There is an AccessViolationException log.
I know that this occurs when using C++ code or native code because C# manages memory without directly touching it.
Among them, there is a part that uses native code, so this part is suspicious.
    {
        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

        private IntPtr hookId = IntPtr.Zero;
        private LowLevelKeyboardProc proc;

        public event Action<Key> KeyPressed;

        public void Start()
        {
            proc = HookCallback;
            hookId = SetHook(proc);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
        }

        private IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                Key pressedKey = KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey(vkCode);

                KeyPressed?.Invoke(pressedKey);
            }

            return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        #region Native Methods
        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        #endregion
    }

Do you see a problem or have a good idea?
Even if an error occurs
It is okay to catch it with a try-catch and not force the program to terminate.
